# rosdep Error With rviz

Tags: rviz, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to build rviz for ROS, but I seem to run into this error:

> $rosdep install rviz

> Failed to find rosdep eigen for package rviz on OS:fedora version:16
> rosdep install ERROR:
> failed to install eigen

How exactly does rosdep do to install dependencies?

Thanks!

-Masoug

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28888/rosdep-error-with-rviz/) by [masoug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1672/masoug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That means that there is no rule for installing "eigen" on Fedora.  You will need to figure out the proper way to install eigen on your own.  You can help future Fedora users by contributing a rule for eigen back, following the instructions here:

http://ros.org/wiki/rosdep

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [masoug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1672/masoug/) on 2012-03-02**:
How do I make these "rosdeps"?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-23**:
See the rosdep wiki page: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`yum install eigen3-devel` should do the trick.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [masoug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1672/masoug/) on 2012-03-02**:
I tried that, but rosdep fails to resolve the dependency...

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-03-02**:
Yes, because there's no rosdep rule defined, the dependency check will fail. However, you can ignore this message, and run rosmake anyway.

**Comment by [masoug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1672/masoug/) on 2012-03-05**:
Thanks! Rosmake runs correctly now! :)